# IBM Cloud (Bluemix) React deploy routing error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I've managed to deploy a react app (create-react-app) to Bluemix using cloud foundry with a sataticfile, everything is working fine except form one thing: routing.

I'm using BrowserRouter to manage routing so when you write the url's path manually I get a 404 error. I know I have to configure the staticfile to use the index.html as default, the question is how to configure this file on bluemix.

My build configuration looks like this:
[image]

And my deploy:
[image]

For now I've solved it using HashRoute, but that hash is awful and really bad for SEO as I read somewhere here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, just create a file called: Staticfile with `pushstate: enabled` and save it on the public folder. I was saving it on the src folder so, when the react-app was built the Staticfile wasn't on the root directory.